# How to read sim phone number with Flutter in an Iphone device

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, contacts

I'm looking for a way to read the phone number of a user for both Android and IOS. I searched and find some plugins but they don't support IOS. Is there a way to acheive that ?

Read phone number on an IOS device with Flutter

Comment: You cannot do this on iOS. iOS and Apple care about user privacy.